# Python for .Net and C# extensions - SignalR client in Python (On method not working)

Tags: c#, python, .net, extension-methods, python.net

I'm trying to access Microsoft.SignalR library from Python for .Net in Visual Studio, and some of the implementation of a Hub (IHubProxy) is in an extension: HubProxyExtensions

Python for .Net does not seem to cover extensions in the readme, and I can't find any reference (my google fu is not working in this case.)

I'm able to load the extensions class directly, but calling the method fails:

```
ext = SignalR.Client.HubProxyExtensions
ext.On(self._proxy, method, handle)
```

The extension class loads and reports as a meta class and has methods from the immediate window

```
ext
<CLR Metatype>
dir(ext)
['Equals', 'Finalize', 'GetHashCode', 'GetType', 'GetValue', MemberwiseClone', 'Observe', 'On', 'Overloads', 'ReferenceEquals', 'ToString', __call__', '__class__', '__cmp__', ...]
```

Calling `ext.On()` crashes the process.

Does Python for .Net support extensions at all?  (Or is it just a problem specific to this particular implementation)

---

Update: Doing a simple test on extensions, it looks like Python for .Net does handle extensions properly, so there is something wrong with my call to Signalr specifically... more testing to come.

Answer (score 3):

So I'm going to answer my own question since it turned out to be multiple issues; and I didn't see others addressing this directly.

---

**Action templates**:

The problem in my case is there is no way to bind Action templates in Python for .Net.  So there is no way to call the correct On methods in a hub.

[Someone else found the same issue recently](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/128)

---

**Extensions**:

Python for .Net can call extension methods;  Simply call the static extension method through the extension class like any other static class methods.

C#

```
namespace ExtensionTest
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public string MyMethod(string something)
        {
            System.Console.Out.WriteLine(string.Format("Hi! This is something! {0}", something));
            return something + " something else";
        }
    }
}

namespace ExtensionTest
{
    public static class MyExtension
    {
        public static string MyExtensionMethod(this MyClass myclass, string something)
        {
            System.Console.Out.WriteLine(string.Format("This is the extension {0}", something));
            string somethingelse = myclass.MyMethod(something);
            return somethingelse + " more of something";
        }
    }
}
```

Python:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('ExtensionTest')
import ExtensionTest
obj = ExtensionTest.MyClass()
s = obj.MyMethod('Hi')
print s
s = ExtensionTest.MyExtension.MyExtensionMethod(obj, 'Hello!')
```

Output:

```
Hi! This is something! Hi
Hi something else
This is the extension Hello!
Hi! This is something! Hello!
Hello! something else more of something
```

I'm not sure why this isn't mentioned on the readme for python for .net.

I guess it's *obvious* :)

Comment: pull requests are welcome to pythonnet documentation :)